# What is the difference between Windows Defender Firewall Settings found Locally and in Local GPO?

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

I have a Win 10 machine. The machine is not AD joined but is Azure joined. The FW settings are managed through Intune and I ran across a couple Win FW settings that confused me a bit.

Below, from my machine, I have Win Defender FW w/ Advanced Security settings  with the following settings found by searching for `firewall`:

[image]

I then check my Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc) and I can see the same settings but all profiles are set to `Not Configured` shown below:

[image]

1. Can someone help me understand the difference between the settings located in each location?
2. Which setting supersedes the other?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Group Policy or Local Policy to manage Windows Firewall settings. Doesn't mean you have to. If local policy were to be used to manage the firewall, it may not be possible to modify configuration in the UI.

Also note it is possible to allow or ignore locally configured rules when policy managed firewall settings are applied.

Comment: Understood. From what I'm getting is that FW on a device can be managed either by GP or Local Policy. How about my second question? What if, in the second screenshot (gpedit.msc), all the profiles were set to ```On```? Does the Local GP Policy trump the Local FW policy?